# How to mark documents as marked/deleted in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, nosql

So I have a few choices to temporarily hide (disabled) or permanently hide (deleted) documents from my queries.

I do not plan to "physically" delete data, except when doing maintainance.

What I could do:

- Add two properties like: "disabled: true" and "deleted:false"
- Add a status field like: "status: 'deleted|disabled|other'"
- Turn things around (show only active documents) like: "status: 'active'" or "active: true".

When querying, I could either query for these properties in every query or I could query a mongoDB view, that only returns "active" documents.

The purpose of the database is to help users to find projects they might like to join. I use mongoose too, but many queries might be native mongoDB-queries.

So what might be the "smartest solution" in terms of performance, scalability and potential effort?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a status field.
It is more generic, and if you need to add an extra value you don't need to create a new field, and in case you want to have more that one status (like ACTIVE and ENABLED) you can even set the status field as an array.

I do not understand "Query a mongoDB view", but for me the solution is quite simple.
Just add to ever query `db.collection.find({..., "status" : "deleted"})`

Comment: In SQL I was used to views, mongodb seems to have them too: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/. One of the benefits of Views: I can change them any time without touching the code. Or at least I have to touch it only once.

Comment: A status-array or a status object might be a good solution too. Would be the most flexible.

Comment: Right, I didnt know you could use it as well in Mongo. Thanks!